# Find ZoneId by current time in this zone

Tags: java, java-time

What is the best way to find ZoneId by expected hours in this ZoneId to UTC time?

For example,

Current time in UTC:
2021-10-22T11:40:37.808Z

It's needed to find any ZoneId, where current hours in the ZoneId would be:
17

17-11 = 6 
So we are looking for any ZoneId, which has:
UTC+06:00

For example, it's:
Asia/Kashgar (UTC+06:00)

Comment: That's a weird requirement. Are you sure this is the correct way to solve the problem that you are actually trying to solve? What are you actually trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: It's needed for e2e tests. Every user has it's own timezone. I need to check, that if user logins at 7AM in his timezone time, api returns "access forbidden". To do that, I need to take current time in UTC, find and set user's timezone, where would be 7AM according current time in UTC.

Comment: If it is for testing, how about just using `ZoneOffset.ofHours(6)`? Do you actually need the timezone name for anything?

Comment: I need timezone name, because in the database user's timezone is stored as timezone name.

Comment: Why do you not just call `ZoneId.systemDefault()` if you want to know the user’s current default time zone?

Comment: You can use the solution given on [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html).

Comment: Be aware that the offset from UTC needs not be a whole number of hours.

Comment: If the user’s time zone is stored in the database, why not simply take it from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all `ZoneId`s and the corresponding offsets.

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    System.out.println(zoneIdToOffsetMap()); 
  }

private static Map<String, String> zoneIdToOffsetMap() {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        for (String zoneId : ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()) {
            ZoneId id = ZoneId.of(zoneId);
            // LocalDateTime -> ZonedDateTime
            ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(id);
            // ZonedDateTime -> ZoneOffset
            ZoneOffset zoneOffset = zonedDateTime.getOffset();
            //replace Z to +00:00
            String offset = zoneOffset.getId().replaceAll("Z", "+00:00");

            result.put(id.toString(), offset);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This prints a map like:

```
{Asia/Aden=+03:00, America/Cuiaba=-04:00, ...}
```

If you really want all the `ZoneId`s for a given offset, you can change the above code slightly to return a map of `String -> List<String>` or just a `List<String>` for a single offset as shown below.

```
private static List<String> getZoneIds(String target) {
        List<String> zoneIds = new ArrayList<>();

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        for (String zoneId : ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()) {
            ZoneId id = ZoneId.of(zoneId);
            // LocalDateTime -> ZonedDateTime
            ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(id);
            // ZonedDateTime -> ZoneOffset
            ZoneOffset zoneOffset = zonedDateTime.getOffset();
            //replace Z to +00:00
            String offset = zoneOffset.getId().replaceAll("Z", "+00:00");

            if (offset.equals(target)) {
                zoneIds.add(id.toString());
            }
        }

        return zoneIds;
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
[Asia/Kashgar, Etc/GMT-6, Asia/Almaty, Asia/Dacca, Asia/Omsk, Asia/Dhaka, Indian/Chagos, Asia/Qostanay, Asia/Bishkek, Antarctica/Vostok, Asia/Urumqi, Asia/Thimbu, Asia/Thimphu]
```

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> So we are looking for any ZoneId, which has:
> UTC+06:00

The offset-from-UTC employed by a time zone varies over time. That is the very definition of a time zone: A history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

So we must specify a moment, an `Instant`, for which we want to know the current offset in effect.

In this code below, we use a stream to consider each of all the time zones. For each time zone, we fetch its set of rules, that history of changes to offset. We query those rules for the offset in use at our chosen moment. For the offset returned, we compare to see if it is the offset we want.

```java
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
ZoneOffset targetOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( 6 ) ;
List< ZoneId > zonesUsingDesiredOffset = 
    ZoneId
    .getAvailableZoneIds()  // Returns a `Set` of `String` objects, the names of each known time zone.
    .stream()
    .map( zoneName -> ZoneId.of( zoneName ) )  // Map each zone name to `ZoneId` object.
    .filter(
        zoneId -> zoneId.getRules().getOffset( instant ).equals( targetOffset )  // Filter for zones whose offset at specified moment matches our desired offset.
    )
    .collect( Collectors.toList() )
;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/oUAWxd).

> [Asia/Kashgar, Etc/GMT-6, Asia/Almaty, Asia/Dacca, Asia/Omsk, Asia/Dhaka, Indian/Chagos, Asia/Qyzylorda, Asia/Bishkek, Antarctica/Vostok, Asia/Urumqi, Asia/Thimbu, Asia/Thimphu]